# XML Mapping to Java Object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a Xml Like this

```
<entry>
  <comboBox>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <details>sdfd</details>
  </comboBox>
</entry>
```

In the other entry I have XML like this

```
<entry>
  <numberField>
    <name>xxx</name>
    <details>sdfd</details>
  </numberField>
</entry>
```

I want to map both `comboBox` and `numberField` to the same class in Java called Field

How do I annotate Java Fields in Entry Class?

Comment: While editing your question I noticed that your XML is invalid because you have an opening tag named `comboBox`, but your closing tag is named `combobox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Entry` class you need to annotate the Java field with
[@XmlElements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html)
and list the individual element names there. Like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Entry {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "comboBox", type = Field.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "numberField", type = Field.class)
    })
    private Field field;
}
```

I have added `type = Field.class` in the annotation above only for clarity.
In your case you can omit it. Then JAXB will pick up `Field` from the property type decaration , which has the same desired effect.

The `Field` class can be straight-forward like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Field {

    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @XmlElement
    private String details;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before, but didn't work before because I overlooked one of the xmlElements like comboBox etc but after you answered I tried again and found where I committed the mistake, I will accept the answer, Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make two sub classes of an object which has the common annoted fields.
Each sub class just has to define jaxb @XmlRootElement (number field or combobox)

Comment: I didn't get it Can you post with some example code